# How do I create and distribute a new .NET Core project template?

Tags: macos, .net-core

I've got a custom project template for a .NET Core project that I'd like to make available via `dotnet new <templatename>`. It was developed using Visual Studio Code on Mac OS X.

[This document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/yeoman) discusses creating new projects, specifically for ASP.NET Core, but I want to create and distribute a new .NET Core project *template* that doesn't include ASP.NET. It's just a class library project with some key modifications.

**Question**: How would I create a package for this purpose and distribute it both privately internally and/or publicly? Is it possible to simply package this up as a NuGet or Yeoman package, or is there some other mechanism I need to use?

Comment: http://rehansaeed.com/custom-project-templates-using-dotnet-new/

Comment: For distribution you can create a NuGet package and place all template files in the content folder. Or you can put them on a network share. I also chatted with someone who checks templates into their repo.

Comment: @SayedIbrahimHashimi, can you elaborate on this please.  I have a project template I am working on but I would like to distribute it to customers so they can install it on their systems.

Comment: Here is a 3rd party template that publishes to nuget.org https://github.com/nspec/DotNetNewNSpec.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE: Here is the official team blog: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/04/02/how-to-create-your-own-templates-for-dotnet-new/

We currently have the documentation on a gist, but are working on turning it into a team blog soon.  I will update here when the blog is posted and public.

For now, you can refer to the gist: https://gist.github.com/sayedihashimi/05741c31ca559f1960bef159a5684988

Comment: Above links don't answer how to "distribute it both privately internally and/or publicly".

Comment: They are just NuGet packages, so you can distribute them the same as any other NuGet packages. See https://learn.microsoft.com/nuget/hosting-packages/overview and https://learn.microsoft.com/nuget/hosting-packages/local-feeds.

Comment: I expected them to be available in Visual Studio GUI, the same as we do with old style templates, but it seems they are not (at least for VS 2019).  So the only way to install them is through command line: dotnet new -i <package_id>